# Auto closing curly quotation marks in Vim

Tags: vim, typography, auto-close

I'd like to set up Vim to auto close the pair of ‘ and ’ (curly quotation marks).

I've tried to configure all the five plugins I could find (two autoclose's, surround, closepairs and delimitmate) but with no success. I don't even seem to be able to remap ‘ at all (with `:imap ‘ ‘’<left>` or similar).

I use Vim 7.3 on Arch Linux and uim 1.7.0 input method; I insert ‘ and ’ through a shortcut defined in .XCompose. Remapping works just fine for my other compose-key shortcuts, like ¡! or ¿?.

Comment: What's the encoding you're using? (`:echo &enc`)

Comment: It's utf-8, and my $LANG is en_US.UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

It looks much like a vim bug, in particular, bug with internal vim escape sequences which all start with `\x80` (second byte of the character in question is `\x80`) and encode various things like NULLs, function keys or `\x80` byte itself. I guess you can dig into vim source code and find there how this byte is escaped and try to replace last byte of `‘` with this escape code or wait until this will be fixed (though I won't expect fix to come soon: here is quote from todo.txt

> UTF-8: mapping a multi-byte key where the second byte is 0x80 doesn't appear
>   to work. (Tony Mechelynck, 2007 March 2)

So, you see problem is known for four years and is not yet fixed.)

Comment: Oh… So that's it. Oh dear. Oh well, thanks a lot for the clarification! That's pretty much all I needed to know, even if I might have hoped for a different solution.

Comment: @caminoix There are discussions about replacing very limited `\x80` vim own escapes with CSI sequences as there are much more problems with current implementation: compared to an absolute value of possible modifier(s)+smth shortcuts like `<C-Tab>`, `<C-S-a>`, `<C-»>`, ... vim supports almost none of them, while with CSI all can be supported. When this code will finally be reworked I guess your problem will go away, though it may not happen until vim-7.4 or even vim-8.0.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid recursion with

```
inoremap ' ''<left>
```

Comment: This isn't the problem. `imap a ab<left>` and `inoremap a ab<left>` both work equally well but neither wants to works with ‘. Clearly, the problem lies in remapping ‘ as `imap a ‘’` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a small function:

```
function! CloseQuotes()
    normal! i'' 
    startinsert
endfunction
```

and then map it to `'` in the following way:

```
inoremap ' <ESC>:call CloseQuotes()<CR>
```

The important thing is the exclamation mark in `normal!`, which prevents the mapping being recursive.

Comment: Thanks for trying but this doesn't work. Recursion is not a problem; `imap a ab<left>` works fine. The problem is remapping the curly quote: ‘ (U+2018). `imap ‘ a` contains no recursion and fails the same way.

Comment: @caminoix The fact that `imap something` works fine should not make you write `imap something`. Use `inoremap` unless you can answer the question «Why I can't use `nore` here?», it will save your time as number of mappings that can interfer with each other grows bigger.

Comment: Understood. I guess I was too focused on my current problem to appreciate a general, if not quite relevant, advice.